# What's the Swift norm for alerting your ViewController of changes from your Service layer?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, key-value-observing

I'm currently whipping up a first Swift side project. What I'm trying to achieve right now, is to have my service layer listen for updates to my Firebase database, and then update the view controllers.

The simple Ray Wenderlich tutorial I am on has the ViewController itself creating a FIRDatabase reference, and observing directly which feels far too coupled.

I'd rather my service layer listen for this, and then dole it out to those necessary. There is no KVO in Swift, correct?

What would be an appropriate Swift norm for updating VC's from your service layer? Are Notifications my only recourse here?

EDIT: Is this a desirable thing to do with Firebase. I've not worked with it before. On the plus side, the database will be decoupled from various VC's and be central to the Service layer which is great. On the downside, even though a user is not in a particular view, the service layer will always be observing all sort of changes that perhaps aren't relevant to where the user currently is.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase databases are really cool for what you are trying to achieve. Actually, KVO works on classes that are inherited from NSObject, just the same as it works in Objective-C. Nevertheless, you have plenty other options to update your view controller.

The first one is to use callbacks.

This is a very swifty way to do it. Everytime that the database is updated, you could call a callback that is stored in your service layer. The view controller sets up the callback in the service layer.

For example:

Your service layer:

```
class ServiceLayer {

    var callback: ((Model) -> ())!

    func listenForUpdates() {
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "path")
        ref.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
            guard let modelList = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject], let model = modelList["key"] as? Model else {
                return
            }

            callback(model)
        })

    }
```

And in your view controller, if you have an instance of the serviceLayer or something similar, you can do the following:

```
let serviceLayer = ServiceLayer()
serviceLayer.callback = { model in
    label.text = model.name
    //Update or do whatever you want with the model
}
```

The second way, and my favorite, is to use Rx.

Its the main library for Reactive programming in swift (RxSwift) and gives you many more options. It's pretty hard to get the grip on it at first but it's totally worth it.

The previous example done with Rx would be the following:

```
func listenForChanges() -> Observable<Model> {
    return Observable.create { subscriber in

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "path")
        ref.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
            guard let modelList = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject], let model = modelList["key"] as? Model else {
                return
            }

            subscriber.onNext(model)
        })

        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

And in the view controller:

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
let serviceLayer = ServiceLayer()
serviceLayer.listenForChanges()
    .do(
        onNext: { [weak self] model in
            label.text = model.name
        }
    )
    .subscribe()
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

The differences are not so notorious here, but Rx brings a new paradigm that is really useful in swift.

If you want to further information on Rx, look in the following link http://reactivex.io/